# end of line in stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

Let us say we have a file like:

```
1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

usually we would do a getline(), and then use string stream to parse inside the line. However the getline returns a string for which we create a stringstream. 
Is it possible to get the entire contents of file in a string stream and then parse the tokens, also knowing where the end of line lies ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is not much point in getting the entire file into `std::string` just to put it into a `std::istringstream` and read it: you could read from the `std::ifstream` directly instead. If you really want to get a file into a `std::string`, here are a few variations:

```
std::string s0{ std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() };
std::string s1( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() );
std::ostringstream out; out << in.rdbuf(); std::string s2 = out.str();
```

Obviously, you would just use one of these approaches as each one will consume the input stream `in`. Once you have the file in a `std::string` you can construct an `std::istringstream` from it.

I think you can also use

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << in.rdbuf();
stream.seekg(std::ios_base::beg, 0);
```

avoiding the need to read the content into a `std::string` first.

Comment: I want to use string stream for tokenization, while doing special processing at line end for each line. Is there any way to avoid the setting of string contents from getline to string stream